# Error in inserting statement when inserting

Tags: c#

I am working on c# project and using winform.

Here the problem is the query was working previously but now it is not working

Here the `todaydate` is a `datetimePicker` which is set to short date format
and my datatype of column is `smalldatetime` the error i am getting is

```
 The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a
     smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
    The statement has been terminated.
```

if i have two date time picker one for date and second for time then how can i insert? please can you guide me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently passing in the *text* value, which means something else is having to then parse it as a date. Don't do that. Given that you've got a `DateTimePicker`, you should just use the `DateTime` value it provides:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@today", todaydate.Value);
```

... or create the parameter first with a specific type (`SqlDbType.SmallDateTime`), then set the value using `todaydate.Value`. The important point is to avoid the string conversion.

Wherever possible, you should *avoid* converting values into text. Keep them in their "natural" form (e.g. `DateTime` in this case) for as much of the time as possible: on input, parse into the natural form, and if you can avoid ever converting to a string, do so!

Comment: jon can you help me if i have two date time picker one for date and second for time then how to insert?

Comment: @shariq_khan: Then construct a single `DateTime` value using something like `datePicker.Value.Date + timePicker.Value.TimeOfDay`

Comment: sir value.timeofday will return the current time or the time which i set in the time picker?

Comment: @shariq_khan: Did you try it first? Did you look up the `TimeOfDay` property in MSDN? If it were returning the current time, why would we need the `timePicker.Value` part at all?

Comment: sorry i should look at the msdn first. but thank you sir for helping

Comment: AddWithValue is rarely a good idea. The parameter will be the same type as the value which might cause implicit converions in the database. In an insert statement it is not a big problem but if the parameter is in a where clause it can prevent the query from using an index.

Comment: @adrianm: Point taken, but the main thing is to avoid performing a string conversion. Will add the alternative.

Answer (score 5):

`AddWithValue` determines the datatype of the parameter from the value you pass.

In your case you are passing a string and thus the parameter is passed to the database as a string not as a datetime expected by the database

you should change that line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@today", todaydate.Value);
```

Comment: steve can you help me once more? i have updated my question. of two date time picker then what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `time7` column in database is `smalldatetime` and you tried to assign it a `string`. I don't suggest it.

Try with [`Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx) method like this;

```
command.Parameters.Add("@today", SqlDbType.SmallDatetime);
command.Parameters["@today"].Value = todaydate.Value;
```

or you can use [`AddWithValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) as also like this;

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@today", todaydate.Value);
```

Comment: thank you sir but todaydate.value result in date and time but i have two date time picker one for date and second for time i want date and time to go in single cell